# Input contents of csv column by column into a website Python

Tags: python, csv, selenium, download

Please help me. I'm in a desperate need. I'd like to input the unique contents of a website column by column from a csv file and download the outputs for all the columns into one csv file. [This](http://bioportal.bioontology.org/annotator) is the website and I'd like to download the resulting tables into a csv file. A sample input could be

```
RNA,cancer,biotin
DNA,lungs,biotin
```

My input csv file looks like the above mentioned and I'd like to input RNA,DNA once, get the results, save to a csv file, then cancer,lungs, save results to the same csv file, then biotin (not biotin,biotin) and save the results to a csv file. I've tried this so far.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from urllib2 import Request
import urllib2

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "path")
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip gz")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
browser.get("http://bioportal.bioontology.org/annotator")
popup= browser.find_element_by_class_name("close").click()
sinput = browser.find_element_by_id("annotation_text")
sinput.send_keys("cancer")
ontology = browser.find_element_by_class_name("default")
ontology.click()
ontology.send_keys("National Cancer Institute Thesaurus")
ontology.send_keys(Keys.RETURN);
submit = browser.find_element_by_id('annotator_button')
submit.click()
time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Have you looked in the [sample](https://github.com/ncbo/ncbo_rest_sample_code/tree/master/python) code?

Comment: @HaiVu I have. But it downloads either JSON or XML. I need a CSV file.

Comment: Would you please show me a sample of expected CSV output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this, a part of which is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878832/save-data-to-csv-file-using-python)

```
time.sleep(2)
clickme = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="annotations"]')
data = []
for tr in clickme:
    tds=tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
    if tds:
        data.append([td.text for td in tds])

def chunks(l, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

with open('out.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for a_chunk in chunks(data[0], 6):
        csvwriter.writerow(a_chunk)

browser.close()
```