# Save data to csv file using Python

Tags: python, html, csv, web-crawler

My data, that I've extracted from a webpage looks like below after using print statement.

```
[[u'Neoplasms', u'Medical Subject Headings', u'direct', u'cancer', u'Neoplasms', u'Medical Subject Headings', u'Malignant Neoplasm', u'National Cancer Institute Thesaurus', u'direct', u'cancer', u'Malignant Neoplasm', u'National Cancer Institute Thesaurus']]
```

I'd like to write it to a csv file like this, with each row containing six elements.

```
Neoplasms, Medical Subject Headings, direct, cancer, Neoplasms, Medical Subject Headings
Malignant Neoplasm, National Cancer Institute Thesaurus, direct, cancer, Malignant Neoplasm, National Cancer Institute Thesaurus
```

Please suggest me how I can go about doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python 2.7 you can do as follows:

```
import csv

data = [[u'Neoplasms', u'Medical Subject Headings', u'direct', u'cancer', u'Neoplasms', u'Medical Subject Headings', u'Malignant Neoplasm', u'National Cancer Institute Thesaurus', u'direct', u'cancer', u'Malignant Neoplasm', u'National Cancer Institute Thesaurus']]


with open('out.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerows(data)
```

Update:

To get six element chunks of the input data: one can use the following function from this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python):

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.  """
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]
```

Then to write the chunks, you can use:

```
with open('out.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for a_chunk in chunks(data[0], 6):     
        csvwriter.writerow(a_chunk)
```

Please note, that it is not clear if the input data is a list of many lists, or only one list embedded in other. I assumed the later.

Comment: That's part of it, but OP also wants the items split up into rows of 6 items each.